# How to correctly lay out this Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a this Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_activities"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:id="@+id/show_filter_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_settings"/>

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And onCreate I load this Fragment into the FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/types_spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/classes_spinner" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/venues_list" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this app The page is displayed like this

[image]

As you can see the button is off the bottom of the screen.
How could I change the layout so the button is always at the bottom, so if the ListView would be scrollable if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout. Set your button with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and in a linearLayout put the reste of your views. This linearLayout should be layout_alignParentTop and layoutAbove your first button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/my_button">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/types_spinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/classes_spinner" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/venues_list" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```